# Opening a fragment from within a fragment using TableRows (OnClickListener)

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have an app that has 3 views, the central of which will have a table with several rows. When a certain row is pressed, the left fragment should open passing some information depending on which row was clicked. I know that I need to set properties (is it just onClick?) in the xml files for the rows but am at a loss when it comes to the placement of the onClick function and how to open a fragment when these on click functions tend to be void ones.

My fragment code:

```
import ...; //for brevity
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My other fragment is called MessageFragment if that helps, and I'm using a PagerAdapter to swipe through the three fragments that exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the onClick attribute in the xml layout definition should be possible, but (imho) the more usual way would be using view-ids and setting listeners in Code (or using some kind of dependency injection as a shortcut).

I.e. your layout definition would look similar to:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_1" <!-- Set the id here to something unique! -->
    >
        <!-- something -->
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And in your java code...

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment_layout, container, false);
        // find the view by using its id and set a listener
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.table_row_1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ChatFragment", "Hey, the user clicked table_row_1 !");
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I first attempted, and where you have your Log.d line I had written some code to open a new Fragment, which led to an error saying that the function is void and hence can't return something. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey that sounds like a very simple compile time mistake. Add the code to your question how you open a new fragment!

Comment: I managed to find a way to overcome the void function, however the new fragment I open doesn't seem to fully overlap the current fragment. Thanks for the help though, I think I see a way now.

Comment: Hey, can you still post your final solution? Also, the overlap-problem seems like a different one to this question. Good luck!